# Save Client side time in database

Tags: database, time

I am developing an application, i need date and time of the user who is accessing(ie Client's date time), how can i get it to server side........?

Comment: Is this a web or desktop application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the current time to server, everytime a client connects to the server. I am assuming you client is a web browser. In that case handle the document.onload event, and write a script that can send time to the server, each time the client loads a page.

If you have a different type of client, this would need to be handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can get client time with javascript and send it to server.